# How to call class ref object in c unmanaged dll from c#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, unmanaged

I am trying to call c++ umnamanged dll ref. class object from c# application. DLL function call working with VC++.

My VC++ code is as follows

```
class  METHOD_TYPE CDeskApi
{
public:
    CDeskApi(void);

        /*
    Description : Initiates a connection to NEST system
    Parameters  : 1. serialkey provided to implement the api
                  2. object of CDeskApiCallback implemented

    Return      : 0 in case of success and -1 in case of error  
        */  
    int Initialise(char *serialkey, CDeskApiCallback* callback);
        /*
        Description : Request data from the server
        Parameters  : 1. symbol of interest
                      2. intervals of 1 min, multiples of 1 min, DAILY_PERIOD in case of daily.
                      3. data to be retrieved from. in no of seconds since epoch
                      4. identifier, which is returned in the callback          
        Return      : 0 in case of success and -1 in case of error  
        */      

    ~CDeskApi(void);
};

class METHOD_TYPE CDeskApiCallback    
{
public:    
};


class Myhandler : public CDeskApiCallback    
{    
public:

    virtual int quote_notify( const char* symbol, int size, Quotation *pQuotes, unsigned long echo)
    {
        return 0;    
    };    
};

Myhandler handler;

void Cnest_desk_appDlg::OnBnClickedOk()    
{    
    if(odesk.Initialise("VWAP", &handler))    
    {    
        AfxMessageBox("Error!");

        return;//error
    }    
}
```

and my C# code is as follows

```
[DllImport("DeskApi.dll", EntryPoint = "?Initialise@CDeskApi@@QAEHPADPAVCDeskApiCallback@@@Z")]
static extern void DeskApiInitialize(IntPtr symbol, callback fn);

private delegate int callback(IntPtr symbol, int nMaxSize, ref Quotation pQuotes, ulong echo);

private callback mInstance;

private void btnFetch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr ptrCString = (IntPtr)Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(txtFetch.Text);

    CallTest.DeskApiGetQuote(ptrCString,quote_notify);

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptrCString);    
}

private int quote_notify(IntPtr symbol, int nMaxSize, ref Quotation pQuotes, ulong echo)
{
    return 0;    
}
```

In C# everything works fine but it doesn't call the **quote_notify** function?

Answer (score 0):

Is that the full code? I doubt it because you don't even have any methods in CDeskApiCallback (which presumably is some interface-like class meant for callbacks). Either way, a C++ "callback" object is very different from a .NET delegate, which is how you're trying to use it.

Another major flaw is that you're trying to dll-import a C++ method (CDeskApi::Initialise). That part will work fine, but how are you going to instantiate the C++ class so that you can call Initialise on it?

I'm sure you could somehow get to work with P/Invoke, but for this purposes COM or C++/CLI would be better. Any COM or C++/CLI classes and interfaces will be directly visible to C# without having to write weird marshalling instructions in the C# code.

Comment: Yes. you are right with same que. in my mind. but i dont know much about c++/CLI, So can you provide any link or example for same. thanks